# SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in /Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs

Tags: sql, node.js, localhost, ejs

Estou com um problema ao rodar meu SQL.

Quando eu rodo no localhost, o meu código fica normal.

Segue código.

```
const express = require('express');
const fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

app.set('views', './views');
app.set('view engine','ejs');

const {getHomePage} = require('./routes/index.js');
const {addPlayerPage, addPlayer, deletePlayer, editPlayer, editPlayerPage} = require('./routes/player.js');
const port = 5000;

const db = mysql.createConnection ({
    host: 'localhost',
    user: 'root',
    password: 'r00tpassword',
    database: 'socka'
});

// connect to database
db.connect((err) => {
    if (err) {
      console.log("Não foi possivelse conectar ao mundo");
    }
    console.log('Connected to database');
});
global.db = db;

// configure middleware
app.set('port', process.env.port || port); // set express to use this port
app.set('views', __dirname + '/views'); // set express to look in this folder to render our view
app.set('view engine', 'ejs'); // configure template engine
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json()); // parse form data client
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public'))); // configure express to use public folder
app.use(fileUpload()); // configure fileupload

// routes for the app

app.get('/', getHomePage);
app.get('/add', addPlayerPage);
app.get('/edit/:id', editPlayerPage);
app.get('/delete/:id', deletePlayer);
app.post('/add', addPlayer);
app.post('/edit/:id', editPlayer);

// set the app to listen on the port
app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log('Server running on port: ${port}');
});

Isso foi um app.js que eu peguei do
https://dev.to/achowba/build-a-simple-app-using-node-js-and-mysql-19me
 para fazer um teste de servidor
e pelo visto, funcionou, mas quando eu acessava meu localhost:5000, me retornava isso 

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in /Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs

If the above error is not helpful, you may want to try EJS-Lint:
https://github.com/RyanZim/EJS-Lint
Or, if you meant to create an async function, pass `async: true` as an option.
    at new Function (<anonymous>)
    at Template.compile (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:626:12)
    at Object.compile (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:366:16)
    at handleCache (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:215:18)
    at tryHandleCache (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:254:16)
    at View.exports.renderFile [as engine] (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/ejs/lib/ejs.js:459:10)
    at View.render (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/view.js:135:8)
    at tryRender (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:640:10)
    at Function.render (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/application.js:592:3)
    at ServerResponse.render (/Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/node_modules/express/lib/response.js:1012:7)
SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in /Users/apple/Documents/NodeJS/views/index.ejs while compiling ejs
```

Ele me retornou uns 50 erros escritos a mesma coisa.
Se quiserem saber qual foi os meu `index.ejs` foi exatamente o mesmo de site.

Answer (score 0):

Você configurou 2 vezes as views? 
Primeira configuração:
`app.set('views', './views');` 
`app.set('view engine','ejs');` 
Segunda configuração: 
`app.set('views', __dirname + '/views');` 
`app.set('view engine','ejs');`

Não encontrei onde você está renderizando a view, o problema pode ser esse. Você deve renderizar com `res.render('caminho_da_view')`.
Tenta fazer isso e depois me diz se deu certo.